# Iterating elements of a numpy array by cycling

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a pretty straightforward question that I couldn't figure out quickly from the numpy reference documentation.

Say I have a numpy array `labels = np.array([1, 2, 3])`.
I have another array `arr = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])`.
I'd like to randomly sample indices of `arr`. Say our indices are `[0, 3, 6]`.

Now, I'd like to make the elements corresponding to those indices cycle by one in `labels`. So, since `arr[0] == 1`, we would set `arr[0] = 2`. Since `arr[3] == 2`, we would set `arr[3] = 3`. Since `arr[6] == 3`, we would set `arr[6] = 1`.

so, to recap:

```
arr = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
labels = np.unique(arr)
idx = np.array([0, 3, 6])  # randomly generate indices [0, 3, 6]
new_arr == np.array(2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3])  # this is the array I want
```

This seems like it'd be pretty straightforward, but I can't find an elegant way of doing this quickly!

Comment: Please don't be lazy. If you say you have a numpy array, actually provide that code, you've provided two python `list` objects. Help us help you

Comment: "Say our indices are [0, 3, 6], so that we have a view on arr[0, 3, 6]" It isn't clear what that means. It's not really clear to me overall what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @juanpa added some more explicit code, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, you might combine `np.roll` with `np.random.randint`, i.e.:

```
sample_idx = np.roll(np.random.randint(len(arr), 3), shift=1)                                                                                                                                                                                            
sample = [labels[i] for i in sample_idx]
```

That is, randomly sample 3 indexes and roll them by one. This should be the final indexes to be re-mapped to your labels.

**EDIT**

Got it. You might do it in two steps:

```
new_arr = arr.copy()
new_arr[idx] = np.roll(labels, -1)  # fixed the shift to -1
```

Output:

```
array([2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3])
```

Comment: Sorry, don't think my original post was particularly clear (I edited it a bit). I think `np.roll` is in the ballpark of what I want -- if `arr[i] == labels[j]`, then I think I'd want to set `arr[i] = np.roll(labels, shift=-1)[j]`. Just not sure how to do that all at once. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks! Will this work if `len(idx) != len(labels)`? I think I might have to use `np.repeat` after rolling to make the lengths the same

Comment: Just use something like `np.tile(labels, arr.size).ravel()` before rolling them.